# How to connect Hylafax with modem

Tags: linux, centos, fax

I have hylafax server installed in my centOs device. I am trying to connect my fax modem with it by using faxaddmodem command but it gives error.

> Unable to deduce DTE-DCE speed; check that you are using the
>   correct device and/or that your modem is setup properly.  If
>   all else fails, try the -s option to lock the speed.

in serial port I gave ttyS0.

to get info about ttyS serial port i used dmesg | grep ttyS*  then it gives response-

> console [tty0] enabled
>
> serial8250: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A

please help me

Comment: Have you tried to see [here](http://www.hylafax.org/site1/setup.html).

Comment: yes but actual problem is I have only one serial port in my system and my monitor is connected through it now I am trying to connect my modem with the serial port. and it is giving above mentioned error.